# How to kill GenyMotion emulator from command line

Tags: virtualbox, genymotion, kill-process

I'm trying to close / kill Genymotion emulator within terminal , the thing is that **kill player** is not enough , the vm is still running , I need something that also can kill the vBox's vm instance.

Comment: Are you on Windows, MacOS, or Linux?

Answer (score 0):

Genymotion has a command line tool (`gmtool`) to control the whole software. Here is the doc: https://docs.genymotion.com/Content/04_Tools/GMTool/GMTool.htm

You can simply run this command to stop a device:

```
gmtool admin stop myDevice
```

**Caution:** This is a paid feature

Answer (score 0):

Use `player` utility (located at genymotion/bin directory) with options `--vm-name` and `--poweroff`
Sample:

```
player -n MyEmylator -x
```

Also maybe helpfull my simple script [genymotion_tools.sh](https://github.com/yshinkarev/my-bash/blob/master/genymotion_tools.sh)